# How to make border disappear when there is no content?

Tags: html, css, height, border

I have the following sidebar:

```
div.sphinxsidebar {
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 210px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.2px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    }
```

This div has a wrapper in it:

```
div.sphinxsidebarwrapper {
   padding: 0;

}
```

I looks something like this:

**----------------------------------------**

|--------Table of content----------|

**----------------------------------------**

The issue i am having is that when this div becomes empty, the border looks like this:

**----------------------------------------**

So essentially, the top border coincides with the bottom border and the border is still visible.

How do i make the border disappear for this case.

The issue seems to be that the border has a height associated to it. So to the div, the content is not empty.

Comment: You can apply the border to the inner element if you can, means wrap the content into another tag. Otherwise consider using back-end languages or javascript.

Comment: I suggest you use display: table for div.sphinxsidebar instead keeping the border not collapsed but if you want it to be disappeared you should use javascript to check if empty and set border to none.

Comment: I am having the same behavior when i put the border on the wrapper, also unfortunately, :empty does not work for me for some reason.

Comment: Even whitespace counted as not empty - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no content, as all i am seeing is a line

Comment: A line is considered whitespace - https://jsfiddle.net/kuayqe8m/

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense why its not working then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 solution or JS solutions

**CSS**

**Hide element:**

```
.sphinxsidebar:empty{
    display:none
}
```

**or remove only border:**

```
.sphinxsidebar:empty{
    border: none;
}
```

**JS:
remove element:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('.sphinxsidebar:empty').remove(); });
```

**or remove borders:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('.sphinxsidebar:empty').css({'border': 'none'}); });
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, for some reason :empty is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

When you set the div to empty, also set the display to none.

`display:none;`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, i don't have access to the code that controls the content of the div. So a purely css or JS solution seems to be the only alternative

Comment: Try this maybe? `.sphinxsidebar:empty[style='height: 0px;']{
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Doesn't work either, i think the reason is because the div actually has a height, due to the border.

Comment: One more: `.sphinxsidebar:empty[style*='height: 0px;']{ display: none; }`